# VBScript function to convert hex to unicode

Tags: unicode, vbscript, hex

I have hexadecimal string which consists of  different languages letters.
Please help me with a vb-script function which converts this hexadecimal string to Unicode text.

For **hex string "506F7274756775C3AA73" , I need to get "Português" as output**.

I tried following function, it gives "PortuguÃªs" as output.

```
MsgBox ConvertHexToUnicode("506F7274756775C3AA73")



Function ConvertHexToUnicode(hexString)

Dim Strlen
Dim Charaset_array(20)
Dim i
Dim j
Strlen = Len(hexString)
i = 0
j = 1

Do
    Charaset_array(i) = Mid(hexString,j, 2) 

    i = i + 1
    j = j + 2


Loop While j < Strlen

ConvertHexToUnicode = ""

For Each chara In Charaset_array

If Not(IsEmpty(chara)) Then
    ConvertHexToUnicode = ConvertHexToUnicode + ChrW("&H" & chara )
End If
Next

End Function
```

Comment: What have you tried do you have a [mcve] to share? If this doesn't seem helpful please read [ask] before posting.

Comment: I have edited my question with sample code that reproduces my issue. @Lankymart

Comment: The problem is each Hex value represents 1 byte but some characters will be made up of 2 bytes or more which is why the characters are being mismatched. Because the string has no way of identifying how many bytes each character uses your unlikely to find an automated method of decoding the string.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Mid()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wffts6k3%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to cut your input string into hex numbers (strings), prepend &H to get hex literals, and [ChrW()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws6aa3sf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to build characters:

```
>> s = "00001F00"
>> WScript.Echo Mid(s, 5, 4)
>> WScript.Echo "&H" & Mid(s, 5, 4), CLng("&H" & Mid(s, 5, 4))
>> WScript.Echo ChrW("&H" & Mid(s, 5, 4)), AscW(ChrW("&H" & Mid(s, 5, 4)))
>>
1F00
&H1F00 7936
ἀ 7936
```

Comment: Why do you insist on answering poor quality questions? They provide no example to show that they have even attempted the problem and yet you post an answer which just encourages more to do the same!! If you are not helping the SO community you're hindering it!

Comment: You are just adding to [The Help Vampire Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19673/202529).

Comment: While this question may be poor, its existence did cause google to show it as a top result in my search, which led me to this answer, which provided enough information to help me through my issue. Even if neither was super robust.